# Rails 6 + Webpacker 4 + PostCSS & @font-face + Local fonts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-face, webpack-4, postcss, webpacker

I'm trying to import fonts in my rails 6 app for hours now.
It's a fresh app using Rails 6, Webpacker 4 and PostCSS.

Everything is loaded (with no error) through webpack (css, js, images). Compilation is correct. Image are properly displayed (using css background:url).

**OTF/EOT/WOFF fonts** : Compiled properly and fonts inside my @font-face are loaded and salted by Webpack. The font are not rendered properly in view (I got the default browser font instead).

I think I tried everything I know. I Switched file-loader for url-loader and back, with no success. Changed the folders hierachy, tried different fonts files, absolute urls (resolve-url-loader). Nothing seems to work.

Anyone would be kind enough point me to the right direction or to share a working config of local fonts loading with webpacker on rails 6 and PostCSS ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Here is my config :

javascript > fonts

```
raleway_thin-webfont.woff
```

javascript > packs > application.js

```
require.context('../fonts/', true, /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2|otf)$/i);
import "./application.pcss";
import "js";

require("@rails/ujs").start();
require("turbolinks").start();
require("@rails/activestorage").start();
require("channels");
```

javascript > packs > application.pcss

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  src: url('../fonts/raleway_thin-webfont.eot'), format('eot');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Amaranth';
  src: url('../fonts/Amaranth-Regular.otf'), format('otf');
}
#test-div { font-family: 'Raleway'; }
```

/postcss.config.js

```
 module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
    require('postcss-preset-env')({
      autoprefixer: {
        flexbox: 'no-2009'
      },
      stage: 3
    })
  ]
};
```

/config > webpack > environment.js

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const { environment } = require("@rails/webpacker");
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");
const vue = require("./loaders/vue");
// const url = require('./loaders/url');

environment.plugins.append(
  "Provide",
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    jQuery: "jquery",
    $: "jquery",
    Tether: "tether",
    tether: "tether",
    Popper: ["popper.js", "default"]
  })
);

["css", "moduleCss"].forEach(loaderName => {
  const loader = environment.loaders.get(loaderName);
  loader.test = /\.(p?css)$/i;
  environment.loaders.insert(loaderName, loader);
});

environment.plugins.prepend("VueLoaderPlugin", new VueLoaderPlugin());
environment.loaders.prepend("vue", vue);

// environment.loaders.prepend("url", url);
// avoid using both file and url loaders
// environment.loaders.get("file").test = /\.(tiff|ico|svg)$/i;

module.exports = environment;
```

/config > webpack > loaders > url (not in use)

```
module.exports = {
  test: [/\.eot$/, /\.otf$/, /\.ttf$/, /\.woff$/, /\.woff2$/],
  use: [
    {
      loader: "url-loader",
      options: {
        limit: 10000,
        name: "[name]-[hash].[ext]"
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: can you try this 2 solutions https://makandracards.com/makandra/66853-using-local-fonts-with-webpack-webpacker

Comment: I rewrote the js from scratch, word to word and surprisingly it worked. Should be a typo